# How can I create a temporary numbers table with SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

So I came upon a question where someone asked for a list of unused account numbers.  The query I wrote for it works, but it is kind of hacky and relies on the existence of a table with more records than existing accounts:

```
WITH tmp
     AS (SELECT Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    ORDER BY cusno) a
         FROM   custtable
         fetch first 999999 rows only)
SELECT tmp.a
FROM   tmp
WHERE  a NOT IN (SELECT cusno
                 FROM   custtable)
```

This works because customer numbers are reused and there are significantly more records than unique customer numbers.  But, like I said, it feels hacky and I'd like to just generate a temporary table with 1 column and x records that are numbered 1 through x.  I looked at some recursive solutions, but all of it looked way more involved than the solution I wound up using.  Is there an easier way that doesn't rely on existing tables?

Comment: What's wrong with recursive queries? "Involved" doesn't sound like a measurable criterium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simple answer is no. To be able to make a determination of absence, the platform needs to know the expected data set. You can either generate that as a temporary table or data set at runtime - using the method you've used (or a variation thereof) - or you can create a reference table once, and compare against it each time. I'd favour the latter - a table with a single column of integers won't put much of a dent in your disk space and it doesn't make sense to compute an identical result set over and over again.

Here's a really good article from Aaron Bertrand that deals with this very issue:

https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

(Edit: The queries in that article are TSQL specific, but they should be easily adaptable to DB2 - and the underlying analysis is relevant regardless of platform)

Answer (score 0):

If you search all unused account number you can do it :

```
with MaxNumber as 
(
    select max(cusno) MaxID from custtable
),
RecurceNumber (id) as 
(
    values 1
    union all
    select id + 1 from RecurceNumber cross join  MaxNumber
    where id<=MaxID
) 
select f1.* from RecurceNumber f1 exception join custtable f2 on f1.id=f2.cusno
```